# pandas wide format of occurrences

Tags: pandas, wide-format-data

I am trying to understand if there is a smarter or clearer way to solve this transformation.
I have a dataframe (long format) with the columns users and the column permissions.
I would like to have a binary matrix with these two columns.
I know it should be easy but all the examples i find about the pivot function show multiple columns data.

Let's say

```
data = {'user': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],'ermission': [p1, p2, p1, p4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('user')

 Permission
user    
A     p1
A     p2
B     p1
B     p3
B     p4
```

And I would like:

```
 Permission
user  p1 p2 p3 p4
A     1  1  0  0
B     1  0  1  1
```

So this is the solution i found:

```
df_tran = df.pivot(index='user', columns='permission', values=df.columns[1]).fillna(0)
df_tran [df_tran != 0] = 1
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['permission'])`, optionally with `reindex` or a `Categorical`. Alternative: `pd.get_dummies(df['ermission'], dtype='int').groupby(df['user']).max()`